# PHP: Sort array numerically descending

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

this question looks like it should have a simple answer but google and the php manual are being no help to me, maybe I just don't understand what they are telling me.

I have an array **example:**

```
$outcomes_array = array(1,4,2,3,5);
```

It will always contain just numbers, how do I go about sorting this array so that it is always in descending order?

so output I want:

```
$outcomes_array[0] = 5
$outcomes_array[1] = 4
$outcomes_array[2] = 3
```

and so on...

Thanks :)

Comment: `rsort($outcomes_array);`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`rsort()`](http://no.php.net/rsort).

Comment: Thanks I knew it must of been simple :P

Answer (score 9):

```
rsort( $outcomes_array )
```

Note, it is *not*

```
$outcomes_array = rsort( $outcomes_array );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
rsort( $outcomes_array );
print_r( $outcomes_array );
```

Answer (score 2):

- `rsort` is just for a numeric array
- `arsort` is for an array with keys

Answer (score 1):

As the default is SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)
So the code should be:

```
$outcomes_array = array(1,4,2,3,5);
rsort( $outcomes_array, SORT_NUMERIC );//SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
print_r( $outcomes_array );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [2, 1, 22, 1, 3, 134, 3, 43, 23, 4];

function mi($arr){
    $count = count($arr);
    for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $min = $arr[0];

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            if ($arr[$i] <= $min) {
                $min = $arr[$i];
            }
        }
        $ar[] = $min;

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            if ($arr[$i] == $min) {
                unset ($arr[$i]);
                $arr = array_values($arr);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $ar;
 }
print_r(mi($array));
```